# How to send picture to the background so i can see the plane?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

So this is my workplace, i use this as a background image which will help me to modeling the plane but its look like this so i can't see the plane.

[image]

But If I visible the image, this appears.

[image]

So my question is: How can i send the plane in front of picture so i can see it?

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way is to add a *Background image*.

*Add->Image->Background*
This will keep your image always in the back.

[image]

Even when it's physically in front.
[image]

Bonus:
You can change these settings for every image in your viewport.
You can also set your image to only appear in orthographic mode, make it transparent... etc.

*Properties panel->Object Data

These settings are available for every image*.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There diffrent ways:

1st way: Just drag and drop into the viewport

2nd way: In viewport menu: Add->Image->(Reference or Background)

3rd way: Use as Camera background. This can be seen in Camera only.